# CodeFirst generating database

Tags: model-view-controller, code-first

I've tried using CodeFirst lately and I'm wondering something.
I used CF to generate db(MyDB.mdf), then I deleted a table (Category) in SQL Server. Next, when I've tried to recreate a new table, CF didn't generate new table in my database.
Here's my code

```
public class Product
{        
    public int prodID { get; set; }        
    public int catID { get; set; }
    public string prodName { get; set; }        
    public Double Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{        
    public int catID { get; set; }
    public string catName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class MyDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my connection string so CF can generate db to my SQL Server

```
<add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I don't use SqlCe database b/c i can't open it

Any solutions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContext>());
```

to the application start method in your global.asax file
[EF4 Code First create new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047900/ef4-code-first-create-new-table/7047949#7047949)

Comment: Yes, I've read about it but this will drop or delete the old database and create a new one. It's a problem. I want to keep my data.

I found a solution: when CF generates database, there's a table name dbo.EdmMetadata will be created in database. If I delete this table, I can change database. But I have to redefine the entities and database as well manually. It's seems not a good solution.

Comment: did you read my link. Now EF have SqlMigrations http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx to do that.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I installed SqlMigrations and I got error when execute update-database. I found your post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020928/entity-framework-code-first-sql-migrations-error-could-not-load-type-system-dat. How did you fix it?

Comment: I never succeeded yet. Did you do what they have suggested. What is the eror you are getting?